# URL Malforms while base64 encoding

Tags: php, gmail-api

Scenario:

I am mailing the url of a recently uploaded file in google drive using Gmail API.

Everything works fine. I send the URL of the file like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_lb8LUbyw85T0XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The mail gets delivered, but the problem is that, I got the url in the mail like this

```
 https://drive.google.com/open?id _lb8LUbyw85T0XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So I think the issue is where I encode the content of the mail to base64.

I had searched much in google, but almost all result speak about url safe encoding where i can pass the encoded string in url.

So any one has the solution, please let me know.

thanks in advance.

My Gmail function:

```
/* * *******************************
 * Send the uploaded file path
 * ******************************* */

function SendBackUpFilePath($name, $date, $desc, $path) {
    $client = GetGoogleClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $raw_message = "To: My Name <maymailid@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $raw_message .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode('File backup dated ' . $date) . "?=\r\n";

// Set the right MIME & Content type
    $raw_message .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $raw_message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $raw_message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";

    $raw_message .= "<br><br>The file has been backed up for this day [$date]<br><br>Filename : $name";
    $raw_message .= "<br><br>Description: $desc<br><br>Link: $path";

    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($raw_message), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw($mime);
    $result = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message);
    $googleMessageId = $result->getId();
    echo "Shared Link mailed!";
}
```

Comment: Please some on help.

Comment: I changed the strategy since there is no help from any where. I shortened the url with goo.gl api and send the shortened url

:-)